# Why can't I talk with SQLAlchemy from the Python console?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, console, flask-sqlalchemy

Information that could be useful: Python 3, PyCharm, using a virtualenv, Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLite.

I can talk to SQLAlchemy and modify tables easily by executing temporary `.py` files, but this quickly gets tedious.

For example:

```
import time
import datetime
import config
from app import db, models
from sqlalchemy import desc
import arrow


movies_within_the_last_tf = models.Movie.query.filter(models.Movie.timeadded > tf_hours_ago).count()
```

However, I want to using the console now, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to start interacting with my tables. I've tried every combination of imports, from `import app` to `from app import models, db`, `from .models import models`, every time getting a different error.

Specifically, trying `from models/.models import db` instantly throws a "No module named 'models' error".

My `model.py` imports:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
```

[Here's my project-tree (IMG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zReHX.jpg)

(Yes, there's no Movie table in the screenshot, because that's a new project, and is built identical to my previous one)

So, how can I query, create, and delete columns in a given table, from the Python console? (Pycharm's, but I guess that shouldn't make a difference)

Comment: you'd certainly need an `sqlalchemy.engine` and get a `connection` (sth like `engine.connect()`)somehow. without knowing what is in `app.db` it's hard to tell anything...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you, how does [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4fTjXSxtE0) do it (around the 7:20 mark)? And I never had to use sqlalchemy.engine or connection in my files.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I want to using the console now, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to start interacting with my tables. I've tried every combination of imports, from import app to from app import models, db, from .models import models, every time getting a different error.
>
> Specifically, trying from models/.models import db instantly throws a "No module named 'models' error".

When you want to import local modules, PyCharm's console does not know how to resolve the path to `models`. But it is easy to fix:

- Include your module folder in PyCharm's source root:

  - Right click on folder in Project View
  - `Mark Directory as > Sources Root`
- Go to your preferences and search for `Python Console`

  - Make sure you enable `Add source roots to PYTHONPATH`

Now you can import any local modules in PyCharm's Python Console. (You may have to click "Rerun" to reload the Python Console)